# How to get another window

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm wondering, how to get info from another window. Here what I've tried:

```
        (function() {
        'use strict';
        var newWin = window.open("https://www.google.com");
        newWin.onload = function(){
        alert('test');
        }
        })();
```

alert is never triggering. I've tried everything.

Comment: ```if (newWin.readyState === "complete") {``` - not working either

Comment: It's a cross-origin URL window so you can't access its properties. You'll have to add that URL to your userscript's `@match` so a second instance of your userscript will run in that window. Then the instances can communicate either via postMessage or GM_addValueChangeListener or GM_getTabs.

Comment: But I want to load a new one dynamically.

Comment: If the second URL is unknown (i.e. arbitrary) you'll simply have to `@match` all URL and add some checks to see if this is the second instance e.g. you can store something with  GM_setValue or use the communication methods I listed above to perform a handshake so if it succeeds it would mean this instance is second.

Comment: But how can I add new URL to @match dynamically?

Comment: As my comment above says, match all URLs and use other means of coordination. I won't be able to elaborate without seeing more of the userscript because currently I don't understand the workflow.

Comment: I added another @match and now it's opening windows over and over without stopping )

Comment: That's because you need to add a check as I explained in my comment. This is something programming is for. BTW there should be examples of such multi-instance communication so try finding them.

Comment: I added a check and it works. Thanks, wOxxOm.